# Tensorflow Object Detection on Google Cloud is very slow

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm using Tensorflow 2.0 Object Detection API to train a model following this guide (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_training_and_evaluation.md)

The checkpoint I'm using is SSD ResNet50 V1 FPN 640x640 (RetinaNet50), which has the following config details:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 7
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_keras"
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      min_depth: 16
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00039999998989515007
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: RELU_6
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.996999979019165
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00039999998989515007
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: RELU_6
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.996999979019165
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
        }
        depth: 256
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
        use_static_shapes: false
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 2.0
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 8
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.03999999910593033
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.013333000242710114
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "{MY_BUCKET_PATH}/data/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 25000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "{MY_BUCKET_PATH}/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "{MY_BUCKET_PATH}/data/train.record"
  }
}
eval_config {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
}
eval_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "{MY_BUCKET_PATH}/data/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "{MY_BUCKET_PATH}/data/test.record"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to submit a job to ggcloud's ai platform with the following command:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training {my_job_id_here} \
    --runtime-version 2.1 \
    --python-version 3.5 \
    --job-dir={MY_BUCKET_PATH}/train \
    --package-path ./object_detection \
    --module-name object_detection.model_main_tf2 \
    --region us-east4 \
    -- \
    --model_dir={MY_BUCKET_PATH}/train \
    --pipeline_config_path={MY_BUCKET_PATH}/data/pipeline.config
```

However, the job runs very slowly (takes it 1 hr to run 100 steps), but I wonder if this is because I don't use GPU/TPU (since I'm learning on the free tier in which they give you free $300 credits), or is it due to any detail in my config file? Is there any way/tuning I can make to make it run faster?

Comment: Yes, most likely that's because you are trying to train on CPU.

Comment: I agree with @Frightera. Please, try running the same model on Google Colab with a TPU or GPU backend, and compare the performance.

Comment: Thanks Frightera, @jccampanero, I wonder (since I use the object detection checkpoint config files instead of building my own model) how can I use it on Google Collab? Or could you point me to any resources that discuss this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course. Please, consider for instance [this article](https://blog.roboflow.com/train-a-tensorflow2-object-detection-model/) and the companion  Colab notebook. I hope it helps.